# Error with facebook feed dialog

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I tried to create a button to share, using direct URL, as shown [**here**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/).

But I got an error. The code:

```
href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed? app_id=364547240322699& link=https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/& picture=http://www.rankingmetrohockey.com.ar/img/anunciantes%2Fflick_interna.jpg& name=Ranking+Metro+Hockey+-+Anunciante+-+Flick+Bag& caption=Ranking+Metro+Hockey& description=Nueva+funda+porta+palo%2C+canilleras%2C+protector+bucal+y+objetos+personales.& redirect_uri=http://www.rankingmetrohockey.com.ar/anunciantes/index/Flick+Bag/3"
```

How to debug this problem? They need to give any permission to the application? You can also just use a link to share?

I do not use Open Graph meta-tags since, on the same page there is another main button to share that uses OG.

Answer (score 6):

Add `&show_error=true` to the end of the link so Facebook will show you the error and you can see what's going on.